# IIS 7 : Don't Require Authentication when on LAN?

Tags: iis, iis-7

On IIS 7, I'd like to make it so that:

- User from LAN (192.168.1.*) - No Authentication Required
- User from Internet - Requires Password

I'm new to IIS from Apache, and I did it on that.

Answer (score 3):

Sure...

You setup two IIS sites pointing to the same content.  Each IIS site has a different IP (this way you can use the same DNS name).  Setup your internal DNS so that it points to the site thats set to anon.  On your external site, nat to the IP thats setup for authentication.

Alternative two, if your clients are on the domain, just add your site to thier trusted sites zone and set it to auto login.

Comment: Are you still need 2 sites when you can enable only "integrated authentication"?

Comment: if you're on a domain, no.  Simply add the web site to your trusted sites (or intranet zone) and then make sure auto logon is enabled.  See this link http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd572939(office.13).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a single site if your server is in an Active Directory and you enable Digest Authentication. The public users will ignore it. Your intranet users will be authenticated using their Windows Active Directory credentials.

For more control, you can do like one of the previous posters said, and use 2 IIS instances running on different IP addresses or different host names on the same IP address (virtual host). This has the added benefit of using Forms authentication for the public users and Windows Digest authentication for your Intranet users.

Either way, once you have the user logged in, you can specify which users or groups should be allowed access based either on their Membership roles or their Windows Active Directory group memberships.